# Error when import skchem ( ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessorProperty' of panda)

Tags: pandas

I have installed scikit-chem by (https://scikit-chem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) by conda. But when I call skchem in python, I got this error:

```
">>> import skchem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/long/anaconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.5/site- packages/skchem/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import pandas_ext
  File "/home/long/anaconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.5/site- packages/skchem/pandas_ext/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
     from .structure_methods import StructureMethods
  File "/home/long/anaconda3/envs/p3/lib/python3.5/site- packages/skchem/pandas_ext/structure_methods.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pandas.core.base import NoNewAttributesMixin, AccessorProperty
ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessorProperty'
>>> "
```

Comment: can you try pip install scikit-chem  and then try importing it.

Comment: @vrana95 I have tried and still got the same error.