# ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessorProperty'

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to install a package named scikit-chem, which contain this line:

from pandas.core.base `import NoNewAttributesMixin, AccessorProperty`

But when this package tries to import form pandas, it gets the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessorProperty'

I've checked the pandas source code and cannot found any class named AccessorProperty.
Fixing the whole package is too much for me, I just want to know this class AccessorProperty has been replaced by what class? Or any class in panda that has the same function.
For example, this is how scikit-chem use this class:

```
mol = AccessorProperty(StructureMethods, _make_structure_accessor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to your version of Pandas. The scikit-chem environment.yml specifies Pandas v0.18.1 as a dependency (see [here](https://github.com/lewisacidic/scikit-chem/blob/546a0fba038dcf5df7d13680a2c4cf8d6ded56eb/environment.yml#L33)). AccessorProperty is available in that version of Pandas (see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/87b0f4dc1e91571cc4dd933b7cb181b99606ad20/pandas/core/base.py#L225)). It also seems that the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/lewisacidic/scikit-chem/blob/master/requirements.txt) for scikit-chem doesn't specify version numbers, so it will probably try and install the latest version if installing via pip (AccessorProperty isn't located in base.py for Pandas 0.24.2).

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell out the solution:
 Try downgrading your pandas installation with `pip install pandas==0.18`

Also related to: [Error when import skchem ( ImportError: cannot import name 'AccessorProperty' of panda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424193/error-when-import-skchem-importerror-cannot-import-name-accessorproperty-of)